# R - How do you to count number of rows associated within two group_by() functions?

Tags: r, dplyr, data-manipulation

I have a dataset (see example below) in which each individual underwent two sessions, each with 4 trials. In each trial they could either pick correctly (1) or incorrectly (0) as designated by the **y** variable. I am trying to calculate the rate correct choices per individual per session. (*This is an example dataset, the real one is larger and has many more rows so I don't want to do this by hand*)

```
df
head(df, 16)
   row name session_number y
1    1  Tom              1 1
2    2  Tom              1 1
3    3  Tom              1 0
4    4  Tom              1 0
5    5  Tom              2 1
6    6  Tom              2 0
7    7  Tom              2 1
8    8  Tom              2 0
9    9  Rob              1 0
10  10  Rob              1 1
11  11  Rob              1 0
12  12  Rob              1 1
13  13  Rob              2 0
14  14  Rob              2 1
15  15  Rob              2 0
16  16  Rob              2 1
```

For example, I want to know that Tom, on his first session, picked correctly in 0.50 of his trials. This is calculated by summing Y and dividing by the number of rows associated with "Tom" AND "Session 1". I can't seem to figure out how to calculate those number of rows though in a larger dataset.

I tried using group_by() and mutate(), but I still can't seem to get it to work because the count() is not working.

```
by_name_by_session <- df %>%
  group_by(df$name) %>%
  group_by(session_number) %>%
  mutate(rate = (sum(df$y)/count(df$name)))
```

Thanks in advance to anyone who can help!

Comment: Do you need `df %>% group_by(name, session_number) %>% mutate(rate = mean(y))`.  BTW, `count` requires a data.frame/tibble as input and not a vector

Comment: you should check `?count`, it is not supposed to be used like that, inside `mutate()`.